# Regex For Acceptable and Unacceptable "PO Box" Addresses

Tags: c#, regex

I have two lists of strings: Acceptable PO Box variations, and Unacceptable PO Box variations.

```
List<string> validPOBox = new List<string>() { "PO BOX", "POST OFFICE BOX", "etc..."}
List<string> invalidPOBox = new List<string>() { "P. BX", "PO BX", "etc..."}
```

I figure I need loop through each list and do something like this with a Regex to see if there is a match:

```
private bool IsPOBoxRegexMatch(string addressLine, string poBoxLine)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "Something", poBoxLine, "SomethingElse");
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

    return regex.IsMatch(addressLine);
}
```

An example would be:

- **PO Box 123** = Valid
- **PO BX 123** = Invalid

How would I build the "pattern" for this Regex?

(I am coding this in C#.)

Comment: You have a list of valid formats and want to dynamically build a regex from it? Or is the list just input for testing, and you want to build a regex by hand that matches all the items in the valid list and none of the items in the invalid list? Can we assume anything that's not on the valid list, is invalid, including "Box Of Posting" and even "mzzyplk 29"?

Comment: Depending on your format, you may be able to get away with a simple set of `String.StartsWith()` checks. That's assuming your `validPOBox`es are always prefixes.  As an aside, wouldn't anything not in `validPOBox` implicitly be invalid? I would think `invalidPOBox` is redundant.

Comment: What if `string` is neither in `validPOBox` nor in `invalidPOBox`, e.g. `My Value 123`? You, probably, don't want `invalidPOBox`: if string in *not* valid it's *invalid*

Comment: There will be two different checks.  I excluded how I'm going to use code, and kind of combined questions.  One view allows PO Box addresses, but only of a certain pattern.  One view does not allow PO Box addresses at all, so anything in either list would be invalid.

Comment: Could probably start off a regex string with something, using a `string.Join` on each of your lists with a `Regex.Escape` for each list item (so the period isn't interpreted as a regex character) and then end the regex string. Then compare the address line to the assembled string.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot All of my variations could use the "String.StartsWith()", so that may be a simpler approach.

Comment: Maybe [`if (validPOBox.Any(m => addressLine.IndexOf(m, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)) Console.WriteLine("Valid");`](http://ideone.com/No63Gw) is enough?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of regex is what you're looking for `(PO Box |POST OFFICE BOX )\S*`, shown here on a java example.

```js
var value = "PO Box 123 ,PO Bx 123"

var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("PO Box |POST OFFICE BOX )\\S*", "gi")
);

document.writeln(matches);
```

```
string text = "PO Box 123";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(PO Box |POST OFFICE BOX)\S*");

var matches = regex.IsMatch(text);
Console.WriteLine(matches);
```

This in c# should return a bool if it can find a match of that regex for a string.

The Regex works in two stages:

1. It first matches "(PO Box |POST OFFICE BOX )" with the "PO BOX " or "POST OFFICE BOX "
2. It then match any non white-space character from 0-n times matching as many as possible using \S*

Should you want only letters or numbers you could use \w* instead on \S* or \d* for just numbers. The Java implementation is currently case insensitive but the c# is not to do the same declare your regex like this `new Regex(@"PO Box \S*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` instead.

If you have many different valid PO box parts stored in a list and you know that the next parts are always numbers you could use this regex `([a-zA-z]+\s{1})+` to match any words befor numbers and then test inf they are in your valid list. Using valid.Contains(match) and `Match` instead of `IsMatch` when running your regex.